# IE8 unspecified error in javascript file

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I had an unspecified error in IE8 in my jquery-1.3.2.min.js file at line:19;

I dont know how to fix it because that file has lot of functions.

is there any solution for this problem to fix this error?...

Comment: This is the definition of vague. That said, I've had problems where I've tried to work with an element that I just created in JQuery *before* adding it to the document. For example, IE didn't like me using `.hide()` on an element unless it was `.append()`ed first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not in jQuery but in the code that calls it.

From a machine that has IE9 or IE10, run the same page, use F12 to get developer tols on, and run in IE 8 browser (user agent) and DOM mode (both), run the debugger from there and see in the stack trace what calls in your code reached this line.

Comment: You mean there are no other JS files in the page? If you just don't know which file has the call, that's why I mentioned using IE developer tools debugger. You should see a tab in the developer tools showing you stack trace when the error happens, if it didn't show, press the debug (a green arrow similar to "Play" button in a media player, or "Run" button in Visual Studio) and it should show you the hierarchy of calls.

Comment: I include 3 JS files in the page... i will try in IE8 with developer tools to identify the error..